# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ""

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, interop, delete-row

I'm having trouble deleting(DELETE) rows. Everytime I add column names in my `string sql` it shows the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ". This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource = '" + fileLocation + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand();

myCmd.Connection = myCon;

string sql = "DELETE * FROM [" + tablename + "$] where _date = '" + full_date + "'";

myCmd.CommandText = sql;
myCon.Open();

myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

myCon.Close();
```

For Example my `string sql` value is

`"DELETE * FROM [Sheet1$] where _date = '03 09 2015'"`

It would produce this error:

> Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression "_date = '03 09
>   2015'"

I have no problems when inserting data in my excel file but when it comes to delete it says this error.

Comment: You do not use `*` for the delete statement and its as `delete from`

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also `_date` column should be some date/time type instead of character IMO:. And use `using` statement to dispose your connections and commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this i.e., remove the `*`, it is not required with `DELETE` statement:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM [" + tablename + "$] where _date = '" + full_date + "'";
```

Also the value which you are getting in `full_date` doesnt seem to be in correct format. Do check the value which you are getting in `full_date` with the format in which you are having in your table.

**On a side note:**

You code is prone to SQL Injection. You need to use prepared statement to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean about the `full_date`?

Comment: @JoeyLorenzoPascual:- I am not sure but thought that the `full_date` ie, your variable which contains the date does not have the correct format of the date.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your query, please remove `*` from your query, hence your query may look like the following: you can check the syntax [here:](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-delete-query.htm)

```
 string sql = "DELETE FROM [" + tablename + "$] where _date = '" + full_date + "'";
```

And the query you are using will opens a wide way for [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), so better approach is to use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
 string strQuery= "DELETE FROM @TableName where _date = '@date'";
 usin (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery)){

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tablename+"$" );
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", full_date );

       myCon.Open();

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 }
```

Comment: Yes, I will definitely consider this. Thank you

Comment: Will parameter `[@TableName]` work as a `table name`?

Comment: `cmd.Close();` is a bad style, use `using` instead

Comment: is the $ supposed to be missing after the @TableName?